# Passing variable to included view with databinding not working in Android Studio 3.0 with built tools 26.0.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

After I updated to Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 and bumped build tools and support library to 26.0.1 with compile and target sdk versions set to 26 passing variables to included layouts is no longer working.

The following code was working before but is no longer working:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/list_empty_layout"
    layout="@layout/empty_list_state_layout"
    app:viewModel="@{viewModel.listStateViewModel}" />
```

In my included layout I have the following

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="viewmodels.BaseListStateViewModel" />
</data>
```

As I said, this was working before with build tools 25.0.3
Anyone have the same problem?

**Edit:**
I also forgot to mention that I updated the android gradle plugin to the following

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Its important to

```
invalidate the cache and restart
```

after you have a full

```
clean
```

Its a common bug using databinding.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but this does not help. Tried this several times to no avail. I realise now though that I forgot to write that I also updated the android gradle plugin to 3.0.0-beta2

Comment: Did you check the generated code? Maybe since upgrading you've a syntax error somewhere in your layouts